# How to transform the regular datatype to array in cloud data fusion wrangler

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

In my source table i have regular data type string and i want to add transformed columns with array type in cloud data fusion like below in wrangler.how can convert regular data type to array like this in wrangler or do we have any other solution to do that in cloud data fusion

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does your input look like? If it's a JSON array you can follow this guide - https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/1722482693/Parsing+and+exploding+JSON+arrays+in+Wrangler

Comment: My input is regular table and I need output in array format what   wrangler logic I need to use to get my output in array format

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, you are reading a single column from a table which is of string datatype. You want to use wrangler to convert this column into an array?

1. What does your string input look like? Is it a json or a delimited string or something else?
2. What would you like for the converted array to look like?
   An example with a sample input string and the output array would help understand better.

Comment: Hi Sneha, 

To clarify, you are reading a single column from a table which is of string datatype. You want to use wrangler to convert this column into an array? 

Ans :: Yes
And i have added my expected input and output  in my question